# Some problems with a jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am working for the first time with jQuery and I'm trying to make an animation on a div. The first animation goes well but the second one (when I want to return the div to its original position it just resets. I cant figure it out.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


// Row one - column one.
$(document).on('click', '#row_one_column_one', function() {

    $('#row_one_column_one').animate({
        left: '35%',
        opacity: '0.9',
        height: '500px',
        width: '500px'
    });

    $('#row_one_column_one_button').fadeIn(750);
}); 

$(document).on('click', '#row_one_column_one_button', function() {
    $('#row_one_column_one_button').fadeOut(250);
    $('#row_one_column_one').animate({
        left: '100px',
        opacity: '0.5',
        height: '250px;'
    });
}); 


});
```

I also made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c1he2vb8/4/

Please spare me I'm still a noob.

Comment: Just a suggestion. When you're comfortable with jquery check out [gsap](http://greensock.com/gsap). It can do a lot more with less code than jquery. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of event delgation (bubbling), the parent div click is triggering and re-executing the animation event, that why it is resetting.

In order to fix this problem you need to add `e.stopPropagation()`  to the click button that shall stop the delegation and execute only the click method of the "click me" button:

```
$(document).on('click', '#row_one_column_one_button', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#row_one_column_one_button').fadeOut(250);
        $('#row_one_column_one').animate({
            left: '100px',
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '250px;'
        });
    });
```

Check the documentation for event propagation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that after your first animation both jQuery functions get triggered, because they lay over each other.

I removed one and added an active class using jQuery:

```
    // Row one - column one.
    $(document).on('click', '.test', function() {

        $(this).animate({
            left: '35%',
            opacity: '0.9',
            height: '500px',
            width: '500px'
        });

        $(this).addClass("active");
    }); 

    $(document).on('click', '.test.active', function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '100px',
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '250px;',
            left: '0%',
                    width: '14%',
                    height: '100%',
            opacity: '1'
        });
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c1he2vb8/11/